# Are prayers only accepted when offered in a Synagogue?

Tags: halacha, tefilla, talmud-gemara, synagogue, tractate-brachot

I've always believed that "all prayers are accepted", at least if they're done correctly and with intention. But I was recently reading through [Berachot 6a](http://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.6a.22/en/Tractate_Berakot_by_A._Cohen,_Cambridge_University_Press,_1921?qh=prayer%2Bsynagogue&lang=en&layout=block&sidebarLang=all) when I read the following:

> אין תפלה של אדם נשמעת אלא בבית הכנסת שנאמר
>   A man's prayer is only heard [by God] when offered in a Synagogue ...

Is a man's prayer really only heard by G-d when offered in a Synagogue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Art Scroll Brachos 6a1 note 18 cites *Lechem Mishna* to *[Hilchos Tefillah 8:1](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/920171/jewish/Tefilah-and-Birkat-Kohanim-Chapter-Eight.htm)* that this refers to a prayer definitely being accepted. If someone prays on his own, then he is judged to determine whether or not he merits his prayer being accepted. The *Tzlach* says that an individual who prays in a synagogue will have his prayer accepted more readily than an individual who prays elsewhere. Note that the quote from the gemara is in the singular and not the plural. The *Mishna Berurah 90:28* cites the *Pri Megadim* to say that a minyan is always superior (and more readily accepted) even if the minyan is in a private house and the individual is in the synagogue.

Comment: But why does it say that it is ONLY accepted at a Synagogue? Shouldn't it say that it's better because so and so?

Comment: @Gabe12 As I say in the first sentence it is **only** accepted definitely in a synagogue. It may or may not be accepted elsewhere (as the *Lechem Mishna* says).

Comment: @Gabe12 the Lechem Mishna was bothered by your very question which is why he interpreted the Gemara non-literally, as an exaggeration.